# Using Ruby popen and PostgreSQL createuser

Tags: ruby, shell, rake, popen

I am attempting to write a very simple rake task (and merge it into a rather large rake task) that will call the following command and pass in a randomly generated password. For the moment, let's even fake the random generation and just give it a set password of 'test':

```
createuser -SDPRE test
```

The code I have for my task is as follows:

```
desc "Create a test user with test password"
task "test" do
  puts('Creating User')
  IO.popen "createuser -SDRPE test", 'w+' do |io|
    io.write "test\ntest\n"
    io.close_write
  end

  raise 'createuser failed' unless $?.success?
end
```

The `io.write` appears not to work as I still have to enter the password. It's also not being clobbered. After running the task and entering the password manually, I can use that password to log in with `psql`.

I have tried quite a few variations such as `io.close`, opening the file as `'w'` and even `'r'` or `'r+'` because I saw other examples that use it.

I am a bit stumped on how to get this to work. Any ideas/comments/answers would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit 1:** This is on a Debian (Lenny) Linux system in case it makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `createuser` is opening `/dev/tty` to read the password

Programs that read passwords usually sacrifice the Unix tools paradigm with respect to passwords. This is a reasonable thing to do because it allows other functionality to respect standard input and output, and put it all on pause while it opens `/dev/tty` for an interactive password.

In any case, an `strace(1)` reveals that `createuser` is in fact opening `/dev/tty`.

All is not lost, `createuser` is just a link to `/usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper` which is a Perl program. I'm sure it can be hacked for password scripting compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Good to know that it simply doesn't work :-)

Comment: Thanks, I always wondered (although obviously not enough to actually find out) how that stuff work: why piping sql to psql doesn't break the standard password prompt, but asks me to type it in instead... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer to your question, but have you considered creating PG user by using SQL instead of invoking shell commands?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/sql-createuser.html

It seems safer and more reliable.

Comment: I had considered that previously, but I was hoping to find another method since using this method, the password will be echoed to the screen. I might be able to block it, but I doubt it. Then again, this will all be run under the root account.